How long before can I apply for new schengen visa before it expires?
My current Schengen visa (Multiple Entry visa issued by Netherlands) is expiring on 15th August . This was the 4th Schengen visa (which was valid for 2 years) . I am applying for the 5th time and my appointment date is on 2nd August in San Francisco VFS center  . I have been visiting my sister in Netherlands every year on first week of September  and my visit has always been for 10 days (So I have not overstayed my visa anytime) .
Can I reapply for my Schengen tourist visa 15 days before it expires ? I am planning to travel in Septemeber and my current Schengen visa expires on 15th August .


Can I reapply for my Schengen tourist visa 15 days before it expires ? I am planning to travel in Septemeber and my current Schengen visa expires on 15th August.

Yes, you may apply 6 months before the start of the intended visit, so you are well within the range that is allowed.
The new visa will be valid starting the day after the old visa expires. So even if your planned trip starts on the 1st of August, you would be covered for the whole period of your stay as long as the 90 days permitted has not been exceeded.


Schengen Visa Code
Article 9
Practical modalities for lodging an application

Applications shall be lodged no more than six months, and for seafarers in the performance of their duties no more than nine months, before the start of the intended visit, and, as a rule, no later than 15 calendar days before the start of the intended visit. In justified individual cases of urgency, the consulate or the central authorities may allow the lodging of applications later than 15 calendar days before the start of the intended visit.
...



Thank you Mark for your answer
